# How to escape quote inside a double-quote?

Tags: c#, html

I am adding a table with html:

```
string _table = @"{
                        ""version"": {""number"": 2},
                        ""type"":""page"",
                        ""title"":""Table"", 
                        ""space"":{""key"":""" + postdata.key + @"""},
                        ""body"":{""storage"":{""value"":""<table><tbody><tr><th><p><strong>Project Basic Informations</strong></p></th></tr></tbody></table>"",""representation"":""storage""}}
                        }";
```

And I want to style `<th>` with `colspan="2"` so the header spans two columns.

I tried the following but it doesn't work: 
`""<table> <tbody> <tr> <th colspan=""2""> <p><strong>Project Basic Informations</strong></p> </th>....""`
or `<th colspan=\"2\"`

Is there a way to escape the double-quotes and get the `<th>` colspan attribute to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

single-quote on HTML attributes also works. you can write `<th colspan='2'>`

Answer (score 1):

Just put the \ inside the string:

```
    string table = "\"<table><tbody><tr><th colspan = \"2\"><p><strong> Project Basic Informations</strong></p></th>....\"";
```

Or you can use the ascii code of the double-qoute:

```
    char quote = (char)34;
        string table = quote + "<table><tbody><tr><th colspan = " + quote + "2" + quote + "><p><strong> Project Basic Informations</strong></p></th>...." + quote;
```

Or you can use single-quote as [MohammdReza Keikavousi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13273944/mohammdreza-keikavousi) said.

Answer (score 0):

You can use / before any escape characters or else simply use single quote
eg: " I/"m StackOverflow " else " I'm StackOverflow"

Comment: That should be a backslash (  \ ) and will not work inside a verbatim string (`@".."`)